# How webpack HotModuleReplacementPlugin works and what does it do？

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

（I'm not good at English, if there is any problem that I did not describe clearly, please remind me to modify）,

I often see some questions or articles about why `webpack hmr` does not work or why my webpack dev server config is invalid or how to config webpack hmr.

But has anyone tried to study the working principle behind webpack hmr in the past, The `HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js` has nearly 400 lines of code, what it is actually doing, I know he will generate a runtime code to insert into the entry, but I want to know,what does it do by subscribing to these hooks? If anyone knows, can you briefly describe it to me? I am trying to understand him at the moment, but it is a bit difficult with my ability, but I am very interested in webpack, and I will be grateful！！！

ps:

```
// source code
/*
    MIT License http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
    Author Tobias Koppers @sokra
*/
"use strict";

const { SyncBailHook } = require("tapable");
const { RawSource } = require("webpack-sources");
const Template = require("./Template");
const ModuleHotAcceptDependency = require("./dependencies/ModuleHotAcceptDependency");
const ModuleHotDeclineDependency = require("./dependencies/ModuleHotDeclineDependency");
const ConstDependency = require("./dependencies/ConstDependency");
const NullFactory = require("./NullFactory");
const ParserHelpers = require("./ParserHelpers");

module.exports = class HotModuleReplacementPlugin {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options = options || {};
        this.multiStep = this.options.multiStep;
        this.fullBuildTimeout = this.options.fullBuildTimeout || 200;
        this.requestTimeout = this.options.requestTimeout || 10000;
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        const multiStep = this.multiStep;
        const fullBuildTimeout = this.fullBuildTimeout;
        const requestTimeout = this.requestTimeout;
        const hotUpdateChunkFilename =
            compiler.options.output.hotUpdateChunkFilename;
        const hotUpdateMainFilename = compiler.options.output.hotUpdateMainFilename;

        console.log("multiStep:",multiStep,"fullBuildTimeout:",fullBuildTimeout,"requestTimeout:",requestTimeout,"hotUpdateChunkFilename:",hotUpdateChunkFilename,"hotUpdateMainFilename:",hotUpdateMainFilename)

        compiler.hooks.additionalPass.tapAsync(
            "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
            callback => {
                console.log("HotModuleReplacementPlugin-compiler hooks additionalPass multiStep",multiStep)
                if (multiStep) return setTimeout(callback, fullBuildTimeout);
                return callback();
            }
        );

        const addParserPlugins = (parser, parserOptions) => {
            parser.hooks.expression
                .for("__webpack_hash__")
                .tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    ParserHelpers.toConstantDependencyWithWebpackRequire(
                        parser,
                        "__webpack_require__.h()"
                    )
                );
            parser.hooks.evaluateTypeof
                .for("__webpack_hash__")
                .tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    ParserHelpers.evaluateToString("string")
                );
            parser.hooks.evaluateIdentifier.for("module.hot").tap(
                {
                    name: "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    before: "NodeStuffPlugin"
                },
                expr => {
                    return ParserHelpers.evaluateToIdentifier(
                        "module.hot",
                        !!parser.state.compilation.hotUpdateChunkTemplate
                    )(expr);
                }
            );
            // TODO webpack 5: refactor this, no custom hooks
            if (!parser.hooks.hotAcceptCallback) {
                parser.hooks.hotAcceptCallback = new SyncBailHook([
                    "expression",
                    "requests"
                ]);
            }
            if (!parser.hooks.hotAcceptWithoutCallback) {
                parser.hooks.hotAcceptWithoutCallback = new SyncBailHook([
                    "expression",
                    "requests"
                ]);
            }
            parser.hooks.call
                .for("module.hot.accept")
                .tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", expr => {
                    console.log("HotModuleReplacementPlugin- parser.hooks module.hot.accept expr",JSON.stringify(expr))
                    if (!parser.state.compilation.hotUpdateChunkTemplate) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (expr.arguments.length >= 1) {
                        const arg = parser.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]);
                        let params = [];
                        let requests = [];
                        if (arg.isString()) {
                            params = [arg];
                        } else if (arg.isArray()) {
                            params = arg.items.filter(param => param.isString());
                        }
                        if (params.length > 0) {
                            params.forEach((param, idx) => {
                                const request = param.string;
                                const dep = new ModuleHotAcceptDependency(request, param.range);
                                dep.optional = true;
                                dep.loc = Object.create(expr.loc);
                                dep.loc.index = idx;
                                parser.state.module.addDependency(dep);
                                requests.push(request);
                            });
                            if (expr.arguments.length > 1) {
                                parser.hooks.hotAcceptCallback.call(
                                    expr.arguments[1],
                                    requests
                                );
                                parser.walkExpression(expr.arguments[1]); // other args are ignored
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                parser.hooks.hotAcceptWithoutCallback.call(expr, requests);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            parser.hooks.call
                .for("module.hot.decline")
                .tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", expr => {
                    console.log("HotModuleReplacementPlugin- parser.hooks module.hot.decline expr",JSON.stringify(expr))
                    if (!parser.state.compilation.hotUpdateChunkTemplate) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (expr.arguments.length === 1) {
                        const arg = parser.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]);
                        let params = [];
                        if (arg.isString()) {
                            params = [arg];
                        } else if (arg.isArray()) {
                            params = arg.items.filter(param => param.isString());
                        }
                        params.forEach((param, idx) => {
                            const dep = new ModuleHotDeclineDependency(
                                param.string,
                                param.range
                            );
                            dep.optional = true;
                            dep.loc = Object.create(expr.loc);
                            dep.loc.index = idx;
                            parser.state.module.addDependency(dep);
                        });
                    }
                });
            parser.hooks.expression
                .for("module.hot")
                .tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", ParserHelpers.skipTraversal);
        };

        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
            "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
            (compilation, { normalModuleFactory }) => {
                const hotUpdateChunkTemplate = compilation.hotUpdateChunkTemplate;
                if (!hotUpdateChunkTemplate) return;

                compilation.dependencyFactories.set(ConstDependency, new NullFactory());
                compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(
                    ConstDependency,
                    new ConstDependency.Template()
                );

                compilation.dependencyFactories.set(
                    ModuleHotAcceptDependency,
                    normalModuleFactory
                );
                compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(
                    ModuleHotAcceptDependency,
                    new ModuleHotAcceptDependency.Template()
                );

                compilation.dependencyFactories.set(
                    ModuleHotDeclineDependency,
                    normalModuleFactory
                );
                compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(
                    ModuleHotDeclineDependency,
                    new ModuleHotDeclineDependency.Template()
                );

                compilation.hooks.record.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    (compilation, records) => {
                        if (records.hash === compilation.hash) return;
                        records.hash = compilation.hash;
                        records.moduleHashs = {};
                        for (const module of compilation.modules) {
                            const identifier = module.identifier();
                            records.moduleHashs[identifier] = module.hash;
                        }
                        records.chunkHashs = {};
                        for (const chunk of compilation.chunks) {
                            records.chunkHashs[chunk.id] = chunk.hash;
                        }
                        records.chunkModuleIds = {};
                        for (const chunk of compilation.chunks) {
                            records.chunkModuleIds[chunk.id] = Array.from(
                                chunk.modulesIterable,
                                m => m.id
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
                let initialPass = false;
                let recompilation = false;
                compilation.hooks.afterHash.tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", () => {
                    let records = compilation.records;
                    if (!records) {
                        initialPass = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!records.hash) initialPass = true;
                    const preHash = records.preHash || "x";
                    const prepreHash = records.prepreHash || "x";
                    if (preHash === compilation.hash) {
                        recompilation = true;
                        compilation.modifyHash(prepreHash);
                        return;
                    }
                    records.prepreHash = records.hash || "x";
                    records.preHash = compilation.hash;
                    compilation.modifyHash(records.prepreHash);
                });
                compilation.hooks.shouldGenerateChunkAssets.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    () => {
                        if (multiStep && !recompilation && !initialPass) return false;
                    }
                );
                compilation.hooks.needAdditionalPass.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    () => {
                        if (multiStep && !recompilation && !initialPass) return true;
                    }
                );
                compilation.hooks.additionalChunkAssets.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    () => {
                        const records = compilation.records;
                        if (records.hash === compilation.hash) return;
                        if (
                            !records.moduleHashs ||
                            !records.chunkHashs ||
                            !records.chunkModuleIds
                        )
                            return;
                        for (const module of compilation.modules) {
                            const identifier = module.identifier();
                            let hash = module.hash;
                            module.hotUpdate = records.moduleHashs[identifier] !== hash;
                        }
                        const hotUpdateMainContent = {
                            h: compilation.hash,
                            c: {}
                        };
                        for (const key of Object.keys(records.chunkHashs)) {
                            const chunkId = isNaN(+key) ? key : +key;
                            const currentChunk = compilation.chunks.find(
                                chunk => chunk.id === chunkId
                            );
                            if (currentChunk) {
                                const newModules = currentChunk
                                    .getModules()
                                    .filter(module => module.hotUpdate);
                                const allModules = new Set();
                                for (const module of currentChunk.modulesIterable) {
                                    allModules.add(module.id);
                                }
                                const removedModules = records.chunkModuleIds[chunkId].filter(
                                    id => !allModules.has(id)
                                );
                                if (newModules.length > 0 || removedModules.length > 0) {
                                    const source = hotUpdateChunkTemplate.render(
                                        chunkId,
                                        newModules,
                                        removedModules,
                                        compilation.hash,
                                        compilation.moduleTemplates.javascript,
                                        compilation.dependencyTemplates
                                    );
                                    const filename = compilation.getPath(hotUpdateChunkFilename, {
                                        hash: records.hash,
                                        chunk: currentChunk
                                    });
                                    compilation.additionalChunkAssets.push(filename);
                                    compilation.assets[filename] = source;
                                    hotUpdateMainContent.c[chunkId] = true;
                                    currentChunk.files.push(filename);
                                    compilation.hooks.chunkAsset.call(currentChunk, filename);
                                }
                            } else {
                                hotUpdateMainContent.c[chunkId] = false;
                            }
                        }
                        const source = new RawSource(JSON.stringify(hotUpdateMainContent));
                        const filename = compilation.getPath(hotUpdateMainFilename, {
                            hash: records.hash
                        });
                        compilation.assets[filename] = source;
                    }
                );

                const mainTemplate = compilation.mainTemplate;

                mainTemplate.hooks.hash.tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", hash => {
                    hash.update("HotMainTemplateDecorator");
                });

                mainTemplate.hooks.moduleRequire.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    (_, chunk, hash, varModuleId) => {
                        return `hotCreateRequire(${varModuleId})`;
                    }
                );

                mainTemplate.hooks.requireExtensions.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    source => {
                        const buf = [source];
                        buf.push("");
                        buf.push("// __webpack_hash__");
                        buf.push(
                            mainTemplate.requireFn +
                                ".h = function() { return hotCurrentHash; };"
                        );
                        return Template.asString(buf);
                    }
                );

                const needChunkLoadingCode = chunk => {
                    for (const chunkGroup of chunk.groupsIterable) {
                        if (chunkGroup.chunks.length > 1) return true;
                        if (chunkGroup.getNumberOfChildren() > 0) return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                };

                mainTemplate.hooks.bootstrap.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    (source, chunk, hash) => {
                        source = mainTemplate.hooks.hotBootstrap.call(source, chunk, hash);
                        return Template.asString([
                            source,
                            "",
                            hotInitCode
                                .replace(/\$require\$/g, mainTemplate.requireFn)
                                .replace(/\$hash\$/g, JSON.stringify(hash))
                                .replace(/\$requestTimeout\$/g, requestTimeout)
                                .replace(
                                    /\/\*foreachInstalledChunks\*\//g,
                                    needChunkLoadingCode(chunk)
                                        ? "for(var chunkId in installedChunks)"
                                        : `var chunkId = ${JSON.stringify(chunk.id)};`
                                )
                        ]);
                    }
                );

                mainTemplate.hooks.globalHash.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    () => true
                );

                mainTemplate.hooks.currentHash.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    (_, length) => {
                        if (isFinite(length)) {
                            return `hotCurrentHash.substr(0, ${length})`;
                        } else {
                            return "hotCurrentHash";
                        }
                    }
                );

                mainTemplate.hooks.moduleObj.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    (source, chunk, hash, varModuleId) => {
                        return Template.asString([
                            `${source},`,
                            `hot: hotCreateModule(${varModuleId}),`,
                            "parents: (hotCurrentParentsTemp = hotCurrentParents, hotCurrentParents = [], hotCurrentParentsTemp),",
                            "children: []"
                        ]);
                    }
                );

                // TODO add HMR support for javascript/esm
                normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser
                    .for("javascript/auto")
                    .tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", addParserPlugins);
                normalModuleFactory.hooks.parser
                    .for("javascript/dynamic")
                    .tap("HotModuleReplacementPlugin", addParserPlugins);

                compilation.hooks.normalModuleLoader.tap(
                    "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
                    context => {
                        context.hot = true;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
};

const hotInitCode = Template.getFunctionContent(
    require("./HotModuleReplacement.runtime")
);


console.log("hotInitCode",hotInitCode)
```